# Excel - Cell Contains a Value from a List - Return list value

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, match, contains

I want to return the corresponding matched keyword that is contained in Column A, but I dont know the Excel query to be used.

Please can you help?

**The details are as follows:**

**Column A** - List of Firms I need to match the Keywords Against (Column C)

**Column B** - If the list of Keywords match the cell in Column A return the Matching value here

**Column C** - Match these keywords to text in Column A, I am looking for a contains match rather than a Exact Match

Here is the file in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zwrqzb60vnadgu8/Test.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: What formulas have you tried?  Have you thought about using VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of suggestions to be entered in B2 and pulled down:-

(1) Case sensitive, must be entered as an array formula, gives last match if more than one matching keyword:-

```
=INDEX(C$2:C$5,MAX(ROW(C$2:C$5)*(1-ISERROR(FIND(C$2:C$5,A3))))-1)
```

(2) Not case sensitive, an ordinary formula, gives first match if more than one matching keyword:-

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$5,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2:$C$5,A2)),,),0))
```

Note that "Affinity Investment Group" won't match because the keyword is "Investments" (plural).

This is the second version with an IFERROR test added so that it shows an empty cell when there is no match:-

[image]

Comment: This is great, would this work on multiple keywords per cell. So if cell A2 had Merchant and Electronics, would it be possible for cell B2 to print electronics + merchant

Comment: The short answer is 'no'. You would need at least Excel 2019 (for textjoin) and preferably Excel 365 and IMO it should be asked as a separate question.