# Excel - Cell Contains a Value from a List - Return list value but avoid returning incorrect value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to implement the very helpful second solution from the question posed here:

[Excel - Cell Contains a Value from a List - Return list value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603660/excel-cell-contains-a-value-from-a-list-return-list-value)

By and large the second solution is working seamlessly, however my data contains one additional problem to overcome.

My list of variables I am searching for includes names of places, and some of those names are contained within other names. However, as "basal" or "root" strings, I am only returning that smaller string rather than the larger string.

I have attached a copy of how this tool is returning the incorrect value.

Does anyone have any idea of how to modify the formula to only return the exact string that I would like? I understand that the order of the entries in the index list has an impact on the return (for example, if Castle was above Castle Hill in the example provided below, it would be both entries, but note that I am working with 16,000 place names in the actual dataset, so making sure all potential permutations are in the right order would be intractable)

[What I am wanting to achieve versus what I am achieving image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNXuP.jpg)

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: @Rory I am using Excel Version 2006

Comment: Which seems strange. I've only just installed it, its Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO

Comment: Do you have the FILTER function available to you?

Comment: Yes I do, but I'm not sure how to deploy it in this context

Answer (score 0):

Doing two things would fix all the errors in your screenshot:

1. Use `FIND()` (case-sensitive) instead of `SEARCH` (case-insensitive). This would fix the Alva and Stow errors.
2. Sort your Location Key Words from longest to shortest. Since your formula returns the first match, this would make it so Port Melbourne would take precedence over Melbourne if "Port Melbourne" were in your String column.

However, this wouldn't fix something like "Stowage Alva" or "Stow Alvan". For that, let's assume that your Location Key Words are always either preceded or followed by a space, or both (because all punctuation was removed beforehand). We can check for both of these cases by replacing <s>`ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$9,A2))` in your formula with:</s>

```
ISNUMBER(1/(IFERROR(FIND(" "&$F$2:$F$9,A2),0)+IFERROR(FIND($F$2:$F$9&" ",A2),0)))
```

`MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($F$2:$F$9,A2)),,),0)` in your formula with:

```
MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&$F$2:$F$9&" ",A2))+(LEFT(A2,LEN($F$2:$F$9))=$F$2:$F$9)*ISNUMBER(FIND($F$2:$F$9&" ",A2))+(RIGHT(A2,LEN($F$2:$F$9))=$F$2:$F$9)*ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&$F$2:$F$9,A2)),0)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked an absolute treat! Normally work with Python to do this kind of work, but work need documentation in Excel.